# What does the Twitter hashtag #壕 mean?

Tags: slang

I'm guessing it's slang and it looks like it has a positive connotation. Like 加油? Or maybe it sounds like 好, it means good? The dictionary says it means air-raid shelter / trench.

Here are some Tweets that use it:

https://twitter.com/search?q=%23%E5%A3%95&src=hash&f=realtime

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is a currently popular Internet slang in mainland China.

> **壕** => short for **土豪** *noun* => "local tyrant", **someone who has much money**.

壕/土豪 is used in a joking occasion, it doesn't mean the person it describes should actually have much money.

**Example**

> A: 我昨天买到了iPhone 5S！ ***I bought iPhone 5S yesterday!***
>
> B: 土豪土豪我们做朋友吧！ ***Tuhao tuhao, let's make friends!*** *(Note: A and B are already friends. That B says so is just to make fun. It is like another expression "你真有钱啊！". But it doesn't mean B really thinks A has much money.)*

#### EDIT

[百度百科【土豪】](http://baike.baidu.com/view/1147101.htm) has well summarized this word:

> 1. 指“暴发户”。
>    ***It means "nouveau riche".***
> 2. 指网络上无脑消费的人，也可以引申到其他领域（网络游戏、电子设备、动漫ACG等）。如某网络游戏中的人民币玩家被称为“土豪”，有时也会简化为“壕”。 
>    ***It means someone who spends money mindlessly on the Internet. And its meaning can extend to other areas ([mindlessly spending money on] online games, electrical devices, or Animation/Comic/Game etc). For example, in an online game, the P4W (pay-for-win) players are called 土豪, sometimes using the short form "壕".***
> 3. 用于讽刺那些有钱又很喜欢炫耀的人，尤其是通过装穷来炫耀自己有钱的人。该意义衍生出“土豪，我们做朋友吧”等句子。 
>    ***It is used to satirize those who have much money but like showing off -- especially those showing off by pretending to be poor. For example, "土豪，我们做朋友吧".***
> 4. 土豪的思想境界文化水平一般都不高，知识面却异常宽泛，但都是了解皮毛之辈。 
>    ***Generally, 土豪 have low ideological and educational level, but broad scope of knowledge.***
> 5. 有些人把比自己肯花钱的人都称之为“土豪”。 
>    ***Some would call those who are more willing to spend money than themselves "土豪".***
> 6. 土豪说简单点就是很土的富豪。 
>    ***In short, 土豪 is rustic but rich people.***

As an Internet slang, 壕/土豪 is very **informal** and its definition cannot be rigorously stated. So it's better to use it only in spoken language or on the Internet.

Comment: 'in an online game, the _paid players_ ...' Do you mean 'the _paying_ players', or more authentic 'the P2W players'?

Comment: BTW, +1 for the last statement that is usually overlooked - many slang do not have a single, coherent definition. Misuse also plays a part in defining their final meaning.

Comment: @NS.X. Yes. Thanks for pointing out the mistake :)